# What does the phonetic symbol after the comma mean here?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

I was checking the [Pronunciation of enshrine](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enshrine?q=enshrine) from ODO which lists:

> Pronunciation: /ɪnˈʃrʌɪn, ɛn-/

Does it mean that there are two different accepted pronunciations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes.  it can either be `/ɪnˈʃrʌɪn/` or `/ɛnˈʃrʌɪn/`.  Usually, the more common is listed first.

Comment: That's British pronunciation, mind you. In American English (K&K) it would be /ɪnˈʃraɪn, ɛn-/.

Comment: Correct, but I was explaining the phonetic notation, not the pronunciation